# Is getting 5 "runs" per page normal?

Tags: 8

I have installed tideways in my Drupal VM and the XHProf module in Drupal.  When I load a single page of my website (the homepage), I am getting 5 "runs" per page.  Is that normal?  The first run seems to have a much higher load than the following 5.

Comment: Yes, this is normal. There are a lot of modules getting or posting data in the background. What URLs are requested by the other runs?

Comment: @4k4 I am not sure.  If I am able to see the URLs, I haven't figured that out yet.  I'd love to know how to find the URL in the output.